# AlertDialog with custom view(with ConstraintLayout) takes all screen space(wrap_content of ConstraintLayout isn't work)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-constraintlayout

I want to show AlertDialog with custom view inside and action buttons(Custom view is ContraintLayout with layout_height=`wrap_content` - LinearLayout works perfect). ContrainLayout really takes small size but parent of ConstraintLayout takes all place at screeen and due this I don't see action buttons.This is happens on Android device where in Settings -> Display -> Screen Zoom has maximul value.

[image]

```
View contentView = 
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_checkbox, null);
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
.setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_309_message))
.setView(contentView)
.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

R.layout.dialog_with_checkbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Why parent of constraintLayout(this is inner implementation of AlertDialog) takes all place on Screen?

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

> Constraint which you given is layout is wrong. check with below layout it's perfect work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:text="Hello World! asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf as "
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Never show this message again."
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is output

[image]